# Find and replace a string in List - Python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
nums = ['Aero', 'Base Core Newton', 'Node']
```

I want to replace the string Base with Fine i.e Fine Core , i tried the below code, but it dint work

```
nums = ['Aero', 'Base Core Newton', 'Node']
nums1=[]
for i in nums:
    if 'Base' in i:
        i.replace('Base','Fine')
        nums1.append(i)

print(nums1)
```

How can i make this work

Comment: Try `nums1.append(i.replace('Base','Fine'))`

Comment: This works however we need to have else to complete this or else only the Fine Core Newton is appended to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` in a list comprehension. That way, it will be simpler to handle multiple occurrences of `'Base Core'` in any elements in `nums`:

```
import re
nums = ['Aero', 'Base Core Newton', 'Node']
new_nums = [re.sub('^Base(?=\sCore)', 'Fine', i) for i in nums]
```

Output:

```
['Aero', 'Fine Core Newton', 'Node']
```

`regex` explanation:

```
^ -> start of line anchor, anything proceeding must be at the start of the string
Base -> matches the "Base" in the string
?= -> positive lookahead, ^Base will not be matched unless the following pattern in parenthesis is found after ^Base
\sCore -> matches a single space, and then an occurrence of "Core"
```

Comment: This works, can you please explain a bit more about this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to drag `re` into this.  If we use the OP's substitution logic with @Ajax1234's loop structure we get:

```
nums = ['Aero', 'Base Core Newton', 'Node']
new_nums = [i.replace('Base','Fine') for i in nums]
```

**RESULT**

```
['Aero', 'Fine Core Newton', 'Node']
```